# The "sendmail" nodemodule is unable to send mails to gmail account

Tags: node.js

I want to send mails without password authentication using node.js modules.

I used "sendmail" to send mails. It's working fine but unable to send mails to gmail accounts.

```js
sendmail({
 from: 'abc@gmail.com',
 to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
 subject: 'test sendmail',
 html: 'Mail of test sendmail'
}, function (err, reply) {
 console.log(err && err.stack);
 console.dir("reply",reply);
});
```

How shall I fix it?

Thanks for your valuable answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to send"? You are getting an error? or what?

Comment: The "sendmail" node module is not able to send mails to gmail users.

Comment: Look at my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45611336/7635845](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45611336/7635845) you will get an idea

Comment: That needs clientId which is not my requirement. I need to send a mail without smtp server as well as without password authentication